# Multiple tumblr tabs, and only those, crash simultaneously in Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, crash, tabs, tumblr

If many tabs are open, and some of them are tumblr blogs, it frequently (several times per day) happens that while loading images on one of these blogs, all open tumblr tabs crash.

The other tabs do not crash, only all tumblr tabs. Even those which are not currently transferring any new data. They all say "Something went wrong. <kbd>Send crash report.</kbd>"

How is this even possible if all tabs are separate processes which don't interfere with one another?

I had this issue on all Windows versions from Windows 7 up, and on all Chrome versions for at least 3 years.

Note that I'm not specifically asking for the cause of the crash (which would be guesswork) or a solution (which likely doesn't exist). I'm asking about how this kind of thing can theoretically happen, because I thought this was absolutely impossible if Chrome worked as advertised.

Comment: Usually this is related to an issue with Flash player, which would explain why it happens across all tabs.

Comment: @CheesusCrust none is installed.